# What is the best analysis method to use in a prospective study using wearable data (fitness trackers) to measure health parameters?

Tags: control-group, sensor-data

I have a prospective study where I need to compare the effect of heat (using an index) on health parameters (heart rate, sleep and steps) of a target population (for example adults with heart disease) compared to a control group (healthy individuals). Both groups will be under the same heat conditions throughout the study. The health parameters will be obtained continously via wearable fitness watches for both groups.
So my independent variable is the heat index and the dependent variables are: heart rate, sleep, steps. All of the variables (heat index and health parameters) will be recorded continously in real time for the duration of the study (about 3 months).

Objective is to investigate if the heat has a higher effect on health parameters of the target group than on the control group.

What is the best analysis method to be able to interpert the results?
I'm a PhD student with limited biostatistics knowledge.